# Unexpected `then' bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement

How do I fix this error? I can't see anything wrong with my syntax.

```
ipcheck() {
  echolog "[INFO] Enabling IP Forwarding..."
  sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
  if[$(cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward) == "0"]
    then
    echolog "[CRITICAL] Could not enable IP Forwarding!"
    exit 0
  fi
  echolog "[INFO] IP Forwarding successfully enabled!"
}
```

I know this is a very basic script, but it's part of a bigger one. The error happens on the then statement.

Comment: a bash tip: use `$(< filename)` instead of `$(cat filename)` -- the former is a builtin construct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shell scripting tends to be a lot more whitespace sensitive than you might be used to if you've come from other programming languages (read: C).  Your `if` line has the problems.  You are probably looking for:

```
if [ $(cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward) == "0" ]
```

The thing to remember here is that `[` is not part of any special `if` syntax - it's the *name of a program* (sometimes a shell builtin).  If you think of it like that, you can see how the command line parser needs it to be separated.  Similarly, the `[` command (or builtin) expects the closing `]` to be separated from its other arguments, so you need a space before it, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I couldn't imagine that this was the solution. You guessed right I came from C.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need a space between `if` and `[`. The lack of a space is confusing bash's parser.

Comment: There also needs to be a space *after* the `[` and before the `]`.

Comment: True, although it will parse without that, just not run.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP will just come back with "My script doesn't work, it says `[$(cat...": command not found`".

Comment: Yeah, it was more a comment on the fact that my double checking of my answer didn't involve actually running the function :-)

Answer (score 2):

Place a space between the `if` and `[$(cat...]` section on line 4.  For this script to run, you'll also need a space on the `]` on the same line.

On a related note, if you're not using indentation in your shell scripts, you should seriously consider it as it makes maintenance and legibility of your code much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly refactored (improved) version that is *not* bash dependant:

```
#!/bin/sh

ipcheck() {
    echolog "[INFO] Enabling IP Forwarding..."
    sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward || {
        echolog "[CRITICAL] Error echoing to ip_forward file"
        exit 1
    }

    # Paranoia check :)
    status=$(cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward)
    [ "$status" = "1" ] || {
        echolog "[CRITICAL] Could not enable IP Forwarding!"
        exit 1  # 1 is error in scripts, 0 is success
    }
    echolog "[INFO] IP Forwarding successfully enabled!"
}
```

Preferably make an `error()` function, perhaps something like:

```
# Call it like: error "[INFO] Could not ..."
error() {
    echolog "$*"
    exit 1
}
```

Oh and yeah, as everyone else pointed out, don't forget the spaces :)