# Bash parsing if ["$s1"=="s2"] as command

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Here's my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
for file in /home/sam/Desktop/RecoveredPix/*
do
  model=$(exif -m -t Model $file)
  if ["$model"=="Canon EOS REBEL T3i"]; then
    echo $file >> /home/sam/Desktop/mypix.txt;
  fi
done
```

Hi,
I have a bunch of pictures that I recovered and am looking specifically for ones taken by my camera, a T3i. I wrote this script the looks at the model in the exif data, and if it were to match "Canon EOS REBEL T3i", its path would be appended to a file. However, upon running this script, I get this returned in the terminal:

```
+ for file in '/home/sammeh/Desktop/100CANON/*'
++ exif -m -t Model /home/sammeh/Desktop/100CANON/IMG_0019.JPG
+ model='Canon EOS REBEL T3i'
+ '[Canon EOS REBEL T3i==Canon EOS REBEL T3i]'
/home/sammeh/Desktop/Search Pix.sh: line 5: [Canon EOS REBEL T3i==Canon EOS REBEL T3i]: command not found
```

This was done on known pictures taken just for a verification of functionality. However, you can see that bash is parsing the if statement as a command for what ever reason. Any help? Thanks!

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 x64

Comment: Quick answer - put a space after the `[`, around the `==`, and before the `]`.  More complete answer: [Unexpected \`then' bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092963/unexpected-then-bash-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the spaces after and before the `[` and `]`, respectively. Probably also around the `==`:

```
if [ "$model" == "Canon EOS REBEL T3i" ]; then
```

Comment: That's because `[` actually *is* a command.  It's builtin in modern shells, but there used to be (and on some systems still is) a `/bin/[` (which is a hardlink to `/bin/test`).  The `if` statement takes *any* command and acts based on its return code.

Answer (score 0):

The shell script language interpreted by bash is pretty weird.  Your problem, here, is that you need to put a space after the `[` and before the `]`.  Also, you need to use a single `=`, not a pair of them like `==`.  Putting it together:

```
if [ "$model" = "Canon EOS REBEL T3i" ]; then
```

Actually, `[` in a shell script is syntactic sugar for the `test` command.  To find out what you can or cannot do with `[`, read the manual entry for test:

```
# man 1 test
```

To the best of my knowledge, in the original Bourne shell, `[` is never a built-in, and when `sh` is running a shell script it relies on an actual executable program `/usr/bin/[`! But in Bash it is a built-in.  So using `[` with Bash avoids the overhead of running an additional process.  Since it is a built-in you should consider the manual page for `bash` to be the final authority on the legal syntax, but I think in practice it is the same as what is documented for the `test` command.

Anyway since in Bourne shell it was an actual command being executed, it needed to have white space after it to separate the command from its arguments, and I guess in Bash they just kept on enforcing that syntax to make Bash scripts more portable to systems using `sh` instead of `bash`.

P.S. I like to use a more modern language for non-trivial scripts.  If you keep working on your script and the shell script syntax becomes painful, please consider rewriting in Python or some other more modern language.