# bash dir/link test failing

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i made a simple script to check if a directory exist and if is or is not a link. But it is not working and i don't know why. Help is requested.

```
if [ -d "$test"] ; then
  if [ -L "$test"] ; then
     echo "1 is a symlink link"         
  else
     echo "DIR 1 found"
  fi  
fi



if [ -d "$test01"] ; then
  if [ -L "$test01"] ; then
     echo "2 is a symlink link"         
  else
     echo "DIR 2 found"
  fi
fi
```

from terminal :

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 zero zero  317 Feb  3 18:22 dir_check.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 zero zero  339 Feb  3 18:17 dir_check.sh~
drwxrwxr-x 2 zero zero 4096 Feb  3 11:15 test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 zero zero   11 Feb  3 18:18 test01 -> /home/zero/
zero@z_pc:~/Desktop/bash_pro$ ./dir_check.sh 
1 is a symlink link
2 is a symlink link
```

The first 1 should have been "DIR 1 found"

Comment: What is `$test`? Did you mean `test` there (that is not a variable expansion)? That `1 is a symlik link` output can't have come from the script as listed since `symlik` isn't in it. Please don't edit your examples here. Do it on your machine and paste exactly what you have and what you get.

Comment: test is a directory and it is not empty. if i remove the dollar sign i get this error : zero@infinity:~/Desktop/bash_pro$ ./dir_check.sh            ./dir_check.sh:  line 4: [: missing `]'
./dir_check.sh: line 14: [: missing `]'

Comment: You need a space between `"test"` and `]` in that line. The `]` is the last argument to the `[` command. And `$test` expands the value of the `test` variable. To test the file/directory `test` you want `test` (or `"test"` but the quotes in this case don't matter).

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and you have my sincere gratitude. Learn something new

Comment: @EtanReisner: ack, just summarized your points in an answer :) wanna copy-paste and take the points?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected \`then' bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092963/unexpected-then-bash-script)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
if [ -d "test" ] ; then
  if [ -L "test" ] ; then
     echo "1 is a symlink link"         
  else
     echo "DIR 1 found"
  fi  
fi



if [ -d "test01" ]; then
  if [ -L "test01" ]; then
     echo "2 is a symlink link"         
  else
     echo "DIR 2 found"
  fi
fi
```

Explanation:
`$test` or `$test01` refers to the value of variable with name `test` and `test01`, not the actual directory names. As commenters pointed out, your code misses a space before the closing `]`, which is the culprit here, plus the fact that you expand non-existing variables, rather than passing strings.